# Commercial Sponge Cake Improver?

Tags: baking, cake, food-science, food-identification, sponge-cake

Many years ago (35+) my grandmother received a container of a 'sponge cake improver' from a family member whom was a commercial baker. 
She describes it as looking like a thick amber liquid or paste.

The method of using it was to put two teaspoons of this improver into a mixer with all the other ingredients, beat on high, and then turn into the cake tin. The result was a high quality sponge, every time.

I've tried searching for what this product might be called, but turned up short.

Without resorting to scouring a commercial baking centre - can someone identify what this commercial sponge cake improver would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search seems to suggest it's a liquid emulsifier. It's not the most natural of products: a couple of E-numbers and propylenes in there.

http://www.rajfoods.net/cake-improvers.html

Click across to Cake Gel Improvers.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the PentaCake cake improver version for sponge cakes: http://www.long-life-cakes.com/pentacake.asp?nodeID=324&itemID=427

Comment: Nice. Are they available outside Israel?

Comment: The PentaCake Gel is exported worldwide, but for industrial use only (1 MT minimum quantity per order).

Answer (score 0):

definitely it was made with emulsifier DMG distilled mono monoglycerides

playing very important role as for as fine texture is concern plus softness bleaching & long shelf life.